# Is Levenshtein distance algorithm performs better than Needleman Wunsch Algorithm?

Tags: performance, time-complexity, levenshtein-distance, needleman-wunsch

I know that both Levenshtein and Needleman Wunsch has the time complexity of O(N*M) but I was curious to know which one performs better than the other and why?

Answer (score 0):

I've studied both of them, both takes the same time, they are equally efficient,
If you want you can see for your self,
just print the cpu_clock times in both the algorithms you wont see much difference,
(maybe just a few ms, but that too differ from compiler to compiler)

There is no article that would go in detail to compare the two, because it is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

These two algorithms do different things, so there is no point in comparing them.

The Levenshtein Distance Algorithm just calculates the Levenshtein distance of two strings (the minimum **number** of mutations needed to transform one into the other).

The Needleman-Wunsch algorithm finds the optimal alignment between two strings, which can be seen as the **operations** needed to transform one string into another.

The first part of this is similar to the Levenshtein Distance Algorithm however, so if a time comparison is needed then Needleman-Wunsch will take longer, purely because it actually does more